# Prevent firebase functions to always update Node.js 10

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

How do I prevent Firebase to always update Node JS?

Every time I put:

```
firebase deploy
```

It updates to Node.js:

```
functions: updating Node.js 10 function ssr(us-central1)...
```

Making it to take so long and using a lot of storage.

I already tried to use `firebase deploy --only hosting` but it obviously doesn't trigger the function.

I just want that firebase resets the SSR function without updating node.
I have done some research too and I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your source code is rebuilt every deployment on Cloud Functions. It's part of the [deployment process](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying#deployment):

> *Deployments work by uploading an archive containing your function's source code to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. Once the source code has been uploaded, Cloud Build automatically builds your code into a container image and pushes that image to Container Registry. Cloud Functions uses that image to create the container that executes your function.*

2. The storage size you're mentioned defines the size of the [execution environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime#execution_environment). It includes the runtime, the operating system, packages, and a library that invokes your function. As mentioned above, even if you deploy a 10MB source code, it doesn't mean that the total size of the image will be 10MB. Storage is needed for the built image as well.
3. `--only hosting` flag deploys your static sites on Firebase. This flag is not intended for deploying functions. Maybe you're referring on specifying function names like `--only functions:funcName`

To answer your question, you can't. It's not possible to update your code and skip updating the execution environment of the function. You may be able to do that if you deployed your code on a VM but Cloud Functions is serverless and managed by Google. Because container images are [immutable](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-operating-containers#immutability), it's not possible to edit a revision. In order to apply changes to your function, it has to be rebuilt every deployment.

Deployment time and storage is a valid concern, that's why devs are usually recommended testing their function locally first, before deploying it to Firebase. You can do that with [Cloud Functions Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator).